# How to write this into an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba

What i am trying to do is copy large amounts of data from a big report (called new report for this question) into the master report.

The code below works fine when there is only one row to get the data from. However, not sure what to do when there are multiple rows with the same ID as its only looking at the **first line and not all the rows**. Why is this a problem? Because sometimes the below condition does not get fulfilled on the first line (shown in the code below)

```
NewReportCell.Offset(0, -93).Value = "-" And _

NewReportCell.Offset(0, -142) = "YES" Then

Sub Interactv4(Optional ByDummy As Byte)

    Dim PK As Variant
    Dim Concat As String
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim tC As String 'tC should represent the column with the concatenate in it
    Dim col(1 To 8) As String
    Dim loc As Range
    Dim NewReportCell As Range

    PK= loc.Offset(0, 2).Value

    If loc.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Not Available" Then
        loc.Offset(0, 80) = "Y"
    Else
        loc.Offset(0, 80) = "N"

        'Line items from the new report
        RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(NewReport.Range("FW:FW"), PK)
        Set NewReportCell = NewReport.Range("FW:FW").Find(PK, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If RowCount = 1 And _
           NewReportCell.Offset(0, -93).Value = "-" And _
           NewReportCell.Offset(0, -142) = "YES" Then

            'A large amount of data is copied from the daily report based on the primary key given above
```

Now, to isolate those rows where there are multiple rows with the same ID, i add the following. However, it's not doing its job as in its still only copy pasting from the first row. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    Else
        If RowCount > 1 And _
           NewReportCell.Offset(0, -93).Value = "-" And _
           NewReportCell.Offset(0, -142) = "YES" Then
```

Comment: Your conditions could be improved. `if NewReportCell.Offset... and NewReportCell.Offset...Then if RowCount = 1 ... Else ... EndIf` No need to test the `NewReportCell.Offset` in two branches, since the offsets and their values are the same in both branches of your code. Start there and see where it takes you.

Comment: Will revise this. Would you know what to write after else so it looks at each row? can i write: else if RowCount > 1 then for each  NewReportCell.Offset(0, -93).Value = "-" And _
    NewReportCell.Offset(0, -142) = "YES" Do something?

Comment: Since already you are using `Find` why not go for `Find` - `do` - `FindNext` - `Loop While` loop.Then testing for other conditions could be performed by an `If` branch inside the do loop. I think 1st RowCount using `SumIf` could also be eliminated.

Comment: Can you give an example, struggling to visualize this because i want to stop the code when it hits "-" and "YES"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like a work for [`AutoFilter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter):

```
If loc.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Not Available" Then
    loc.Offset(0, 80) = "Y"
Else
    loc.Offset(0, 80) = "N"

    With NewReport 'reference NewReport sheet
        With .Range("AK1:FW" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "FW").End(xlUp).Row) ' reference referenced sheet range in columns AK:FW from row 1 down to FW column last not empty value
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="YES" ' filter referenced sheet on it first column (i.e. column "AK") with "YES" content
            .AutoFilter Field:=50, Criteria1:="-" ' filter referenced sheet on it 50th column (i.e. column "CH") with "-" content
            .AutoFilter Field:=143, Criteria1:=PK ' filter referenced sheet on it 143th column (i.e. column "FW") with PK content
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then ' uf any filtered values other than referenced range headers row
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=myOtherWorkbook.Worksheets("masterData").Range("A2") ' copy referenced range filtered values (skipping headers) to you destination workbook/worksheet
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End If
```

this assumes that row 1 of `NewReport` worksheet is the header row of your database

Comment: let me try this and i will get back to you

Comment: So i do not want to copy the entire data, only specific columns, that means i can ignore this line  .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=myOtherWorkbook.Worksheets("masterData").Range("A2") ?